# Is there a law for summing powers of logarithms?

Tags: summation, logarithms, exponentiation

I have the expression

$$(\ln a)^c+(\ln b)^c$$

Is there a way to combine these (i.e., remove the $+$ sign) to create a single expression in terms of $a,b,c$?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I can't work out what to try. Seems like I could somehow take a $log$ of both expressions and then change the base, but I can't see how.

Comment: If we would have terms like $\ c\cdot \ln(a)\ $ , we could convert the expression, but this expression cannot be converted.

Comment: Logarithms are (or at least want to be) exponents. There is no simple rule to deal with (and transform) something like $e^{x^y}$ the way you can transform $e^{xy}$ or $e^{x+y}$, and thus I wouldn't expect there to be any corresponding logarithm rule (for instance, $e^{xy} = (e^x)^y$ corresponds to $y\ln x = \ln x^y$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :

You could simplify the different $\ln (a^c)+\ln (b^c)=c\ln (ab)$ or something similar

but unless you know something special about the relationship between $a, b, c$ then $(\ln a)^c+(\ln b)^c$ is essentially as difficult to simplify as $2^c+3^c$

Comment: So, a general rule clearly doesn't exist. But in its absence, the specific function I'm looking at right now is $\biggl(\ln \bigl(\cos (\ln x)+i\sin (\ln x)\bigr)\biggr)^c+\biggl(\ln \bigl(\cos (\ln x)-i\sin (\ln x)\bigr)\biggr)^c$. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward - That expression introduces the traps of the complex logarithm and powers but there may be possible simplifications  using $\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) = e^{i \theta}$ so it becomes $\left(\log_e \left(\exp (i \log_ex)\right)\right)^c+\left(\log_e\left(\exp(-i\log_ex)\right)\right)^c$ and that *might* be something like $\left(\log_e(x)\right)^c\left(i^c+(-i)^c\right)$